# Are Docker containers cloud-based? How can it consume less resources than a virtual machine?

Tags: docker, virtual-machine

I read many articles about Docker, its use, and how it works, but I still don't understand how Docker containers consume less memory and less space than virtual machines. I don't understand that point.

Let's take an example, I have two computers at home, I launch 3 virtual machines on the first one and I launch Docker containers on the second one. So, both the virtual machines and the Docker containers are using the resources of the main machine. How can Docker containers use less resources than the virtual machines?

Are they cloud-based?

Answer (score 1):

Docker is OS-level virtualization, and VM is hardware-level virtualization.

Docker is not cloud-based but you can run anywhere that has Docker installed, be it your local computer, on-premise, or on the cloud.

Nowadays, all cloud platforms run containers inside a VM. For example, if you install Docker in an AWS EC2 instance you are actually running containers inside a VM.

We said Docker used fewer resources because the VM image includes the whole Guest operating system but Docker relies only on the host Kernel. The start time of a container is way faster than that of a VM. You can pack more containers inside a VM, hence fully utilizing the resource instead of letting the unused resource in the VM idle.